# GL Screenshot Breaks on viewport resize…sometimes

Tags: c++, opengl, screenshot, bmp

I’m developing a plugin for SIMDIS (basically military google earth), written in c++ using VS 2012. It’s a pretty nifty little thing to auto plot points, and one of its functions is to take a series of screenshot of the view-port and save the images off so it can be used/processed somewhere else.  This works fine too… until you re-size the view-port one too many times. Re-size is done by clicking the corner of the window and dragging it bigger and smaller, and the program may launch full screen or windowed mode; either way it works fine the first few sets… or as long as the window is not re-sized.

When it breaks, the program will still march happily along, create the files, and filling them with data at what seems to be an appropriate size for whatever resolution image I’m trying to generate… but the format becomes no-good. It will still be a *.bmp, but windows stops being able to understand it. No errors are thrown though, (I think, I’m not catching any GL errors?[if that’s possible?]).

I can’t get it to consistently happen with a specific number of actions, but it seems to start failing after 3-7 view-port re-sizes. I don’t know if this is a problem with my screenshot code, an issue with the SIMDIS program or plugin, a GL issue, or what. I’ve tested it on multiple machines.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Is there something specific I should be doing that I’m not? Is this a problem native to the parent program (SIMDIS), or something I can work with/around with GL commands I don’t know about?

Screenshot code follows:

```
#include "TakeScreenshot.h"  //has "#include <gl/GL.h>" etc...

TakeScreenshot::TakeScreenshot()
{   
}


std::vector<int> * TakeScreenshot::TakeAScreenshotBMP(const char* filename)
{
    //std::cout << "Screenshot! "; 
    std::vector<int> * returnVec = new std::vector<int>();

    int VPort[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    int FSize = 0;
    int PackStore = 0;

    //get GL viewport dimensions, x,y,w,h into vport
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,VPort);

    //make a framebuffer, RGB
    FSize = VPort[2]*VPort[3]*3;

    unsigned char PStore[8294400];// 4k sized buffer

    //store settings
    glGetIntegerv(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, &PackStore);

    //unpack to byte order
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    //read the gl buffer into our buffer 
    glReadPixels(VPort[0],VPort[1],VPort[2],VPort[3],GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&PStore);

    //Pass back settings
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, PackStore);


    ///
    //set up file info
    ///

    BITMAPINFOHEADER BMIH; //info header
    BMIH.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BMIH.biSizeImage= VPort[2] * VPort[3] * 3;

    BMIH.biWidth = VPort[2];
    BMIH.biHeight = VPort[3];
    BMIH.biPlanes = 1;
    BMIH.biBitCount = 24;
    BMIH.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;//file header
    int nBitsOffset = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + BMIH.biSize;
    LONG lImageSize = BMIH.biSizeImage;
    LONG lFileSize = nBitsOffset + lImageSize;
    bmfh.bfType = 'B' + ('M'<<8);
    bmfh.bfOffBits = nBitsOffset;
    bmfh.bfSize = lFileSize;
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;


    // swap r and b values because GL has them backwards for BMP format.
    unsigned char SwapByte;
    for(int loop = 0; loop<FSize; loop+=3)
    {
        SwapByte = PStore[loop];
        PStore[loop] = PStore[loop+2];
        PStore[loop +2] = SwapByte;
    }

    ///
    // File writing section
    ///


    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(filename, "wb");
    //if something borked

    if(pFile == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "TakeScreenshot::TakeAScreenshotBMP>> Error; was not able to create file (Permisions?)" << std::endl;
        returnVec->push_back(-1);
        returnVec->push_back(-1);
        return returnVec; //exit
    }


    UINT nWrittenFileHeaderSize = fwrite(&bmfh,1,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), pFile);
    UINT nWrittenInfoHeaderSize = fwrite(&BMIH,1,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), pFile);
    UINT nWrittenDIBDataSize = fwrite(&PStore, 1, lImageSize, pFile);

    fclose(pFile);

    //some return data for processing later
    returnVec->push_back(VPort[2]);
    returnVec->push_back(VPort[3]);
    return returnVec;
}


TakeScreenshot::~TakeScreenshot(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a known-good BMP writer like SOIL/DevIL?

Comment: @ Marky - I don't know opengl so I can say a foolishness but... the only point that seem dangerous to me is the `for(int loop = 0; loop<FSize; loop+=3)` cycle where you write `PStore` in position `loop+2`; are you sure that `FSize < 8294398`? Otherwise, this cycle write out of the limits of the `PStore` array.

Comment: @genpfault we sort of want to stay away from 3rd party libraries because they take control away, and have possible licensing issues

Comment: @max66 fsize is initilazed to the size that would be needed to store a 4k monitors screenshot if the whole screen was captured( 3840 pixels × 2160 lines x 3 bytes a px). Which is way overkill for the target environment. (1920x1080 px max). I wrote it this way (for the 3rd time) to remove the dynamic array and any possibility of memory release/dealloc issues.

Comment: One possible problem is that you're not initializing all fields of `BMIH`. Try adding a `= {0}` at the end of the definition. Also, rows in BMP files are 4-byte aligned, and I don't see the necessary padding taken into account in your code.